# Unity how to animate object's position without freezing it's position

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, ragdoll

I am currently working on a unity project and I have a stickman built by Hinge Joints but when I animate his legs and activate the animation, the legs stays at the same position and the rest of the body is moving forward.

How can I animate the legs without freezing it's position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

*Anchor and Axis should be correct, if it works with a motor.
For testing, deactivate "Use Spring", "Use Limits" and "Use Motor".
If it still doesn't move, you should have a look at the rigidbody. "Is Kinematic" should be deactivated as well.*

From [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/hinge-joint-wont-move.57567/)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of time passed since I asked this question and when I read this question again I figured out that my mistake was animating the legs without a parent.
The legs hadn't a parent so their positions where the animation position.
But if I had setted the legs as children of an empty game object, their positions were relative to the empty game object, which I could move as I wish.